# ParcelJS V2 build React files into individual files without CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, shopify, parceljs

Previously, in Parcel V1, when I ran `parcel build src/results/results.js --out-file results.min.js --dist-dir src/theme/assets/`, Parcel would bundle my results file into `results.min.js`, for some unknown reason, they've removed this functionality.

Now, when I remove the `--out-file` argument, it bundles as `results.js` and a random `results.css` is also being produced - this seems to be coming from a node_module I'm using, and importing into my main stylesheet - my styles are handled outside of Parcel so this file is wiping out my own CSS file. I can't seem to find a way to prevent it from doing this.

I'm using this within a Shopify theme so I have multiple React files that are intended to build into their own individual files.